# GLSL Specular Highlight Darker when closer

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader

How can I fix my specluar component so it gets brighter when far and dark when nearer?

I'm using a pointlight by the way and not the default light variables.
If necessary I'll put the lines that calculate the specular component here: (Vertex Shader)

```
//pl_pos is the raw vec3(x y z) before this
vec3 pointlight = gl_ModelViewMatrix * vec4(pl_pos,1.0);
vec3 Norm = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
//Adding Vertex Calc
vec4 VertexPos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
vec3 LightVec = normalize(pointlight - VertexPos.xyz);
float SpecularExp = 128.0;
float NormLightAng = max(0.0, dot(Norm,LightVec));
vec4 Specular = vec4(pow(NormLightAng, SpecularExp));
gl_FrontColor = Diffuse + Specular;
```

Comment: Which illumination model are you using? I wouldn't know of any where the specular component is calculated depending on dot(n, l)^p. Usually it's dot(reflected, view)^p (phong illumination) or dot(n, halfway)^p (blinn-phong). At least, the view-vector should somehow influence the specular illumination.

Comment: Oh and just to clarify ^p means power of the specular component correct?

Comment: Rabbid76 yes you're correct I'll edit that. It should be

Comment: So @BDL Thanks I'll check out Phong illumination. Because i used that formula from the Opengl Superbible where it was using the LightVariables. Actually the lighting works correctly on brighter colors because i was using gray initially

Comment: Uhhh guys problem: When I push matrix then translate the spheres else where then pop matrix the specular highlight is still shining like I translated the light too but it never moved. Meaning infront of the object is shining instead of from where the light still is

Comment: @Rabbid76 ohhh I see so it's not a real specular calculation, Thanks a lot you're the best!

Comment: @TakiiMarskii: did you specify the light position in world space or in view space? Since you transform the vertex position with the Model-View matrix, the light position also has to be in view space.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks for that I have an idea of what you're saying but I cant map it to the code. Please bear with me as I'm good with c++ programming and opengl but glsl is new to me and the formulas are giving me a time of my life! And example of your point will be great!

Comment: @BDL well I did specify in World Space because pl_pos is the raw x, y and z coords

Comment: I'm going to add how the vertex position is calculated as well

Comment: @Rabbid76 using GLM was a plan I had for later though because I want to make sure that my formulas are correct. Is it a case that I should switch now to using GLM?

Comment: @Rabbid76 ohhh awesome Thanks I'll get GLM on it!

Answer (score 0):

@BDL gave the answer saying 
"Which illumination model are you using? I wouldn't know of any where the specular component is calculated depending on dot(n, l)^p. Usually it's dot(reflected, view)^p (phong illumination) or dot(n, halfway)^p (blinn-phong). At least, the view-vector should somehow influence the specular illumination. "

And @Rabbid76 enhanced the answer by saying:
"Note, dot(Norm,LightVec)) is a lambertian diffuse reflection, see How does this faking the light work on aerotwist?"

Thanks a lot for your help guys!